# pastebin api createPasteFromFile error 'createPaste' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, pastebin

I'm creating a log system with node for a twitch chat. When you type "!logs user" it should upload the correct user.txt file to pastebin and give out a link to pastebin in chat.

I'm using pastebin-js and tmi.js

The problem is when I type !logs user it gives out an error in the console

```
C:\gempbot\node_modules\pastebin-js\bin\pastebin.js:137
        this.createPaste(data, title, format, privacy, expiration)
            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createPaste' of undefined
    at C:\gempbot\node_modules\pastebin-js\bin\pastebin.js:137:13
    at fs.js:334:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

CODE

```
client.on('chat', function (channel, user, message, self) {
   if (user["username"] === admins[0] || user["username"] === admins[1] || user["user-type"] === "mod" ) {
       if ( message.indexOf("!logs") >= 0 ) {
            var getNthWord = function(string, n){
            var words = string.split(" ");
            return words[n-1];
            }

            pastebin.createPasteFromFile('./logs/' + getNthWord(message, 2) + '.txt', 'logs for ' + getNthWord(message, 2))
                .then(function (data) {
                    // we have succesfully pasted it. Data contains the id 
                    console.log(data);
                    client.say(channel, 'Logs for ' + getNthWord(message, 2) + 'http://pastebin.com/' + data);
                })
                .fail(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });



       }
   }
});
```

Does anyone have an Idea how do I fix this error? I'm confused what is actually causing the problem.
Here the rest of the code to authenticate in pastebin (which is at the top of my code)

```
var PastebinAPI = require('pastebin-js'),
    pastebin = new PastebinAPI({
      'api_dev_key' : 'censored',
      'api_user_name' : 'censored',
      'api_user_password' : 'censored'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the module. `this` is being used inside a callback and the callback isn't bound to the `Pastebin` instance, so the `this` value is wrong. There's a PR to fix this [here](https://github.com/j3lte/pastebin-js/pull/7).

Comment: well thats a bummer, hopefully they update the branch soon

Comment: The PR was just merged and a new version released with the fix.